# Firebase Push Notification Delivery Receipt

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to know if a Firebase push notification has been successfully delivered to a user's mobile device? If this is not possible via Firebase out of the box, is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in delivery receipt. If you want such a thing, you can build it yourself though:

1. Send only data messages, so that all messages are delivered to your application code.
2. Send a delivery receipt from your code back to your server, e.g. writing it into a Firebase database.